# Sobre JAVA e HeidiSql

Tags: java, sql

Gente estou começando a programar em java,e queria saber se alguém poderia me ajudar me dizendo qual a versão do conector do HeidiSql,para que possa colocar no meu programa,estou usando a última versão do HeidiSql.

Comment: Pode começar aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/heidisql/info

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,

Qual o banco de dados você está tentando usar, mesmo sendo SQL há diversos tipos de bancos de dados que usam a linguagem SQL?

HeidiSQL é um programa que vai te permitir conectar em um SGBD, ou seja, apenas vai fazer com que você possa acessar um banco de dados relacional.

Sugiro que escolha uma linguagem de programação e procure algumas lições sobre programação básica no youtube para ter um norte, pois pela sua pergunta faz-me parecer que está meio perdido no assunto. Caso esteja aprendendo java acho que pode iniciar por este vídeo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGUjvuYFbdE